# Unable to add Microsoft.Azure.Devices namespace to Azure Function run.csx

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function from which I need to send back messages to my devices through IoT Hub.
Every time I try to add the statement:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices;
```

I get the below error:

> run.csx(11,23): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Devices' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Azure' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

But strangely as the error suggests, if I just go for `using Microsoft.Azure`, there are no compilation errors.

So I tried using Devices withing my code, like `static Devices.ServiceClient client;`, but again the same error.

I have also tried using `#r "Microsoft.Azure.Devices`, but that didn't work either.

I tried creating a new Function App service altogether, but the same error just keeps poping up.

My project.json file looks something like this:

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net47":{
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.Azure.Devices": "1.4.1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried using `net46` also.

Small decription of my app:

So my function is supposed to be triggered by a `ServiceBusTopic`, has a `BlobStorage` as an Input.

No idea how am I going to send my data back to my device now that this namespace does not get added.

Comment: I am looking into this. I was able to repro (should be "net46" but you tried that as did I).  In the meantime I can get this to work fine if I use the Azure Functions tools for Visual Studio 2017.  They use .net [class libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library) which are a little easier to deal with than .csx.  See if that works in the meantime and I'll keep poking into this.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a working sample using a **Microsoft.Azure.Devices** nuget package. The trigger is the *ServiceBusQueue* and the *blobName* is an application property of the BrokeredMessage.

run.csx:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices;

public static async Task Run(string inputMessage, string inputBlob, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {inputMessage}");
    log.Info($"Blob:\n{inputBlob}");


    string deviceId = "Device10";
    var c2dmsg = new Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputMessage));

    // create proxy
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myIoTHub2"];
    var client = ServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

    // send AMQP message
    await client.SendAsync(deviceId, c2dmsg);

    await client.CloseAsync();
}
```

function.json:

```
    {
      "bindings": [
      {
        "name": "inputMessage",
        "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
        "direction": "in",
        "queueName": "function",
        "connection": "myServiceBus",
        "accessRights": "Manage"
      },
      {
        "type": "blob",
        "name": "inputBlob",
        "path": "afstates/{Properties.blobName}",
        "connection": "myStorage",
        "direction": "in"
      }
      ],
      "disabled": false
  }
```

project.json:

```
{
  "frameworks": {
  "net46":{
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.Azure.Devices": "1.4.1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Try the following steps:

- delete the file *project.lock.json*
- use the **net46** dependencies
- restore the nuget package pressing the save button.

Watch the logs progress.

Comment: I know the code, but unfortunately that assembly isn't getting compiled on my azure portal function app. It recognizes till Microsoft.Azure, but then its like Devices never existed inside Microsoft.Azure. :(

Comment: I can reproduce your errors using the net47 dependencies, so try the following one more time: delete the file project.lock.json, use the net46 dependencies and restore the nuget package pressing the save button. Watch the logs progress.

Comment: That worked just fine. Thanks a lot. I'll mark this as my answer if you just update this info in it.